# Спиральная матрица из центра, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, матрицы

Помогите сделать заполнения матрицы спиралью из центра.
Уже запуталась в этих индексах.
Вот мои попытки его сделать, но я явно что-то делаю не так...

Ввод:

```
3
```

Вывод:

```
7 8 9
6 1 2
5 4 3
```

Код:

```
print('Input n --> ')

# 6 - квадратная спираль снаружу
n = int(input())

v = [[0] * n for i in range(n)]
m = n

i = 0
j = n - 1
value = n * n

while n != 0:
    k = 0
    while k < n - 1:
        value -= 1
        j -= 1
        v[i][j] = value
        k += 1
    for k in range(0, n - 1):
        i += 1
        value -= 1
        v[i][j] = value
    for k in range(0, n - 1):
        j += 1
        value -= 1
        v[i][j] = value
    for k in range(0, n - 1):
        i -= 1
        value -= 1
        v[i][j] = value
    i += 1
    j -= 1
    if n < 2:
        n = 0
    else:
        n = n-2


for i in range(m):
    for j in range(m):
        print(v[i][j], end=' ' * 3)
    print()
```

На данный момент вывод выглядит вот так:

```
7   8   1   
6   0   2   
5   4   3
```

В каком месте он идёт не туда?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36889800/5909792

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю следующий алгоритм:

```
# Исходная матрица
[
    [1]
]

# Прибавляем столбец справа, для этого перебираем все строки,
# добавляя число в конец каждой (в данном случае 
# матрица содержит одну строку)
[     
    [1, 2] 
]

# Добавляем в конец матрицы новую строку
[
    [1, 2],
    [4, 3] # новая строка
]

# Прибавляем столбец слева, для этого перебираем все строки в
# в обратном порядке, вставляя число в начало каждой
[
    [6, 1, 2],
    [5, 4, 3]
]

# Вставляем в начало матрицы новую строку.
[
    [7, 8, 9], # новая строка
    [6, 1, 2],
    [5, 4, 3]
]

# И т. д.
```

**Решение**

```
from pprint import pprint

def spiral_mtrx(size):
    mtrx = [[1]]
    num = 2
    for i in range(1, size):
        if i & 1:
            for row in mtrx:
                row.append(num)
                num += 1

            mtrx.append(list(range(num + i, num - 1, -1)))
            num += i + 1
        else:
            for row in reversed(mtrx):
                row.insert(0, num)
                num += 1

            mtrx.insert(0, list(range(num, num + i + 1)))
            num += i + 1
    return mtrx

n = int(input())
pprint(spiral_mtrx(n), width = 30)
```

Comment: А что означает запись ' if i & 1: '?

Comment: @lakvak `&` оператор означает побитовое 'И'. Он последовательно сравнивает биты правого и левого числа: если оба парных бита равны `1` в соответствующий бит результата идёт `1`, иначе `0`. Таким образом `i & 1` означает: "верни биты, которые одновременно не равны `0`  в числе `i` и в числе `1`". В числе `1` только первый бит не равен `0`. Соответственно `if i & 1` будет возвращать `True` только когда в первом разряде числа `i` будет **1**, другими словами, когда число `i` будет нечётным. `i & 1` аналог `i % 2 != 0`, только короче.